# Avoid Hitting the Limits when Updating records with a Scheduled Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, limits, loop, scheduled-flow

I have to change the status of some tasks after 30 days. I have already created and tested the flow in my sandbox, the problem I'm having is that in Prod we usually have around 5000 records to expire. I'm not sure how to avoid hitting the limit.
This my current flow, I kept it simple.
I read I could use a a loop and a pause element but I'm not sure how to do this.
[image]

Comment: what makes you think you will hit limits? The schedule-triggered flow will present at most 200 Tasks per transaction and the update element is bulkified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a loop and pause after a batch of records has been executed.

pausing helps you reset your limits.

This thread will help you out.

[Is there a way to update a bunch of records without loop in flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383082/is-there-a-way-to-update-a-bunch-of-records-without-loop-in-flow)

Comment: I saw that thread but I'm not getting where the record collection variable "Temp" is coming from

Comment: So 'Temp' in this context is to basically capture the records I need to work on as a batch(in this case 200 records).

Comment: And when is that variable created? Because I see it's used in the first assignment (before the batch) but that's my doubt, where does it come from? Because it's not a variable created manually

Comment: In the first attached screenshot you can see that it is a record collection variable that has been created